# How send image file to API service?

Tags: c#

I need to send a phone as "File" format to a service, this is my code:

```
     using (var httpContent = new MultipartFormDataContent(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()))
            {

                httpContent.Add(new StringContent(request.Title), "title");
                httpContent.Add(new StringContent(request.Description), "description");         
                **httpContent.Add(new ByteArrayContent(request.Photo), "image");**
                var postResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, httpContent);

                response.Url = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response.Url) ? appSettings.FacebookSettings.BaseAddress + response.Url.Substring(1) : null;

                return response;
            }
```

I am passing image as ByteArray and it is not posting as it needs to be in File format. I am able to choose file in Postman and send it successfully, How I can change the Byte array here to file format and send it?

Comment: Try StreamContent

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use the `Add` overload which takes a parameter for the "filename" of the file you wish to upload.

Your code would look like:

```
httpContent.Add(new ByteArrayContent(request.Photo), "image", "imageFileName.jpg");
```

or

```
httpContent.Add(new ByteArrayContent(request.Photo, 0, request.Photo.Length), "image", "imageFileName.jpg");
```

I used the file extension ".jpg" as an example. You should make the filename and extension appropriate to your file you are uploading.

From MS Docs:

```
Add(HttpContent, String, String)
Add HTTP content to a collection of HttpContent objects that get serialized to multipart/form-data MIME type.
C#

Copy
public void Add (System.Net.Http.HttpContent content, string name, string fileName);
Parameters
content
HttpContent
The HTTP content to add to the collection.
name
String
The name for the HTTP content to add.
fileName
String
The file name for the HTTP content to add to the collection.
```